# Dynamics CRM 2011 E-Mail Router & Exchange 2010 Cluster Error "Incoming Status: Failure - No results were found"

Tags: exchange-server, dynamics-crm-2011

I have what seems a common problem setting up the router to handle incoming mail, but after spending a couple of days implementing the suggestions I ran out of ideas.

The situation is as follows:

All operating systems Win2k8R2 64 bit.

Domain user names are @domain.local

Mail addresses are @domain.com

Dynamics CRM 2011 installed on server CRM.
Exchange server 2010 cluster consisting of 2 mbx servers and 2 cas servers.

Dynamics CRM E-mail Router installed on cas1 server, running as local system.

Service domain account added to PrivUserGroup in AD.
cas1 & cas2 servers added to PrivUserGroup in AD

Service domain account added to CRM as full read-write System Administrator.

Management Role Assignment given to service account to impersonate all account in the domain.

Global Address Book membership checked for the accounts of interest.

Access to GAB from service account checked.

Logged in successfully to both domain & Outlook with all accounts of interest.

I am getting "Incoming Status: Failure: No results were found." error when i try to test access from e-mail router config tool, with the following exception in event log:

```
An error occurred while opening mailbox account@domain.com.
   Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.EmailException: No results were found.
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.ExchangeWSConnector.IsCurrentUser()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.ExchangeWSConnector.GetService()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.ExchangeWSConnector.OpenMailbox()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.ExchangePollingMailboxProvider.InitExchangeConnector()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.ExchangePollingMailboxProvider.OpenMailbox()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.CrmPollingMailboxProvider.Run()
```

When I check the IIS log on cas1 I see that the respective request contains:

```
    2011-09-30 14:19:15 192.168.1.128 POST /EWS/Exchange.asmx ;RC:a744e288-62f0-44bf-b506-
    54f0753fa283;Init>>Conn:0,HangingConn:0,AD:30000/30000/0%,CAS:54000/54000/0%,AB:30000/30000/0%,RPC:36
000/36000/0%,FC:1000/0,Policy:DefaultThrottlingPolicy_a90f4c5f-dfd1-4e99-8a1f-
3cf7adb8ffa3,Norm,Sub:5000/0;ErrorCode=ErrorNameResolutionNoResults;[C]
Queues:0msec/Execute:51.8605msec;SoapAction=m:ResolveNames;Version=1;RpcC=2;RpcL=3;LdapC=1;LdapL=15;E
nd(54.796ms)
 >>Conn:1,HangingConn:0,AD:30000/29986/1%,CAS:54000/53948/1%,AB:30000/30000/0%,RPC:36000/35998/1%,FC:1

000/0,Policy:DefaultThrottlingPolicy_a90f4c5f-dfd1-4e99-8a1f-3cf7adb8ffa3,Norm[Resources:(Mdb)WINDDB
(Health:-1%,HistLoad:0),(DC)DCSRV2.domain.local(Health:-1%,HistLoad:0),],Sub:5000/0; 443 
DOMAIN\serviceaccount 192.168.1.120 Mozilla/4.0+
(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+4.0.30319.237) 200 0 0 91
```

So I understand there is a name resolution issue, but how do I proceed from here?

BTW, Exchange hosts around 10 different Accepted Domains, but the one of interest is set as default one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if anyone runs into the same problem the solution in our case was the following:

In CRM E-mail Router Incoming Profile configuration, account credentials were entered as username@domain. When we changed it to domain\username, the thing worked.