# Dynamics CRM 2011 E-mail Router error: e-mail address is not associated with any approved forward mailbox user or queue record in CRM

Tags: validation, queue, dynamics-crm-2011, router, forward

I am trying to create an email-to-case workflow that converts e-mail messages sent to support mailboxes into CRM cases, but the e-mail router fails to process certain messages during validation (according to the MSCRMEmailLog file). Instead of entering the queue as e-mail activities (which the workflow converts to cases), they pop up as errors in the server's Event Viewer. I have reviewed the numerous posts about e-mail router issues ([external users](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e3da5fb-7088-439a-81ee-1eff6515c9e9/crm-2011-ru4-email-address-is-not-associated-with-any-approved-forward-mailbox-user-or-queue?forum=crmdeployment), [queues pending approval](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmmayankp/archive/2012/05/02/crm-2011-email-router-issue.aspx), and [account credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611868/dynamics-crm-2011-e-mail-router-exchange-2010-cluster-error-incoming-status)), but none of the solutions have fixed my e-mail routing error.

**CRM System Settings** 
*E-mail*: (Selected) Process e-mails only for approved users & approved queues. 
*Queues*: 5 total. Each mailbox address is approved and Incoming/Outgoing options are set to E-mail Router for All e-mail messages. The System Administrator is the owner of each queue.
*Tracking*: (Selected) Track e-mails sent between CRM users as two activities.

**E-mail Router Configuration Settings** 
'Status: Succeeded' for incoming & outgoing messages for all Users & Queues listed for the deployment. 'Status: Succeeded' for all 5 forward mailboxes.

**Other details**
(1) We are using the Visendo SMTP Extender on the server to monitor an e-mail drop folder from which the e-mail router picks up the e-mails.
(2) Sender e-mail addresses associated with CRM (user, queue, etc.) and not associated with CRM result in this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the credentials for the email router to use on each user account?

[image: Email Router Details]

Comment: Even with the setting you suggested, we had to resort to changing the authentication method from IWA to restrict relay permissions to the IP address of the server in IIS. In addition, for the outgoing (SMTP) configuration profile on the e-mail router we changed the access credentials from the dynamic Local System Account to the static System Administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

With either server-side sync or Router setup any mailbox setup for incoming, need a valid e-mail address and NB assigned to a licensed user. Say for instance you have a Queue setup for incoming with an mailbox you would get this error if no user exists in Dynamics with that same address.

I've noted lately that the router wont assign an incoming profile until that is not the case - and will receive this exact error when a mail is send to this Queue.